# no hint path laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Hey guys it's my first time deploying my work online..
I have some couple of routes that work perfectly on my local but when I'm on the server I get this error..

**View [frontoffice.Sondage.list_sondage] not found**

I'm using l5-modular package for modules

it's something like :

```
app/
└── Modules/
    └── Poll/
        ├── Controllers/
        │   └── PollController.php
        ├── Models/
        │   └── Poll.php
        ├── Views/
        |     └── frontoffice
        │          └── Sondage
        |          └── list_sondage.blade.php
        ├── Translations/
        │   └── en/
        │       └── example.php
        ├── routes
        │   ├── api.php
        │   └── web.php
        └── helper.php
```

I'm returning this view :

```
 return view('Poll::frontoffice.Sondage.list_sondage',compact('resultats_groupe','config'));
```

what can be this error coming from?

Comment: You reference your view as part of the ``Views/frontoffice``-directory. But the structure above shows, that your view lies in ``Views/Sondage/list_sondage.blade.php``. So you have to write ``return view('Poll::Sondage.list_sondage', ...);``

Comment: the view is under "/frontoffice/Sondage/"..
I was typing it wrong above..

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload -o`; if that fixes your problem, you need to stop everything and find and destroy typos (namespaces / class names... PSR-2).

Comment: I see from code above that list_sondage.blade.php is not in Sondage folder.. Then you should use `frontoffice.list_sondage`

Comment: @Aleksandrs : that' exactly what I'm doing..
they answered me according to what I mistyped, I just edited now and the view is obviously under frontoffice...

Comment: @AtefRihane if it is directly under frontoffice, then use my code. I didn't get. Your error message sounds like View [frontoffice.Sondage.list_sondage] not found, try [frontoffice.list_sondage] instead

Comment: is this error is for just list_sondage? or for all routes?

Comment: @Leena Patel : some routes work normally  ,some others no.. that's driving me crazy..
Also some other routes show " No hint path defined for []" even though I checked all of them..

Comment: can you try `View::make('Poll::frontoffice.Sondage.list_sondage')` ?

Comment: You need to tell Laravel where to load your views from, so there must be some provider inside your Poll module where you should program that.
Function is loadviewsfrom() and it should be in a serviceprovider inside your module